# Expected length of time it takes the Golem to reach safety?

Tags: statistics

> Iron Golem is an action figure in Minecraft. Iron Golems are loyal to villagers, and will defend them from Hostile Mobs and siege attacks. Suppose that in a particular setting,
>   an Iron Golem is trapped by Mobs in a mine containing 3 doors. The first door leads to a tunnel that will take him to safety after 3 hours of travel. The second door leads to a tunnel
>   that will return him to the mine after 5 hours of travel. The third door leads to a tunnel that
>   will return him to the mine after 7 hours of travel. If we assume that the Iron Golem is at
>   all times equally likely to choose any one of the doors, what is the expected length of time
>   until he reaches safety?

This question feels like I should be approximating it to either the hyper-geometric/negative binomial models and maybe having more than one distribution function. But I'm totally stuck after that thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since two of the three choices lead you right back to the initial state, you can compute the expected escape time fairly easily. Letting $E$ be the expected escape time, we have $$
E=\frac13\cdot3+\frac13\cdot(5+E)+\frac13\cdot (7+E),
$$ therefore $E=15$.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother modeling the full distribution of escape times if all you really need is the expected value. It must solve $T=\frac{3}{3}+\frac{5+T}{3}+\frac{7+T}{3}$.